Django null value in column with default violates not-null constraint
I have this current table, with state as Jsonfield with default a empty dict
class Channel(models.Model):
    agent = models.ForeignKey(Agent, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, blank=True)
    organization = models.ForeignKey(Organization, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    type = models.CharField(choices=ChannelType.choices, max_length=64, default=ChannelType.WHATSAPP)
    settings = models.JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
    state = models.JSONField(blank=True, default=dict)
    disabled = ArrayField(models.CharField(), blank=True, default=list)

But when i try to create a Channel Object
Channel.objects.create(type=ChannelType.WHATSAPP, settings=serializer.validated_data, organization=user_utils.get_user_organization(request.user))

Django raises this error
 django.db.utils.IntegrityError: null value in column "state" of relation "core_channel" violates not-null constraint
Failing row contains (4, WHATSAPP, {"session_id": "611a09fd-ccfd-4683-ba92-4717c9688193"},null, {}, null, 1).

Why? default should not make that the default value a {}? why is working with the field disabled?
